# Angular 2 structure with services

Tags: angularjs, structure

I couldn't find a straight answer in articles, so I am asking You. In angular 2 the components should be divided by their purpose. And it is awesome, you can group view+component(+service) if needed. If the service is used widely (like error message handler or something like that) it can be moved to a separate module. But what to do if only a few components require the service (in my project it communicates with the API to pull specific data) and they do not posses a child-parent relationship - sibling components. Should I still move the service to a separate module so I could inject it or should I break the DRY and write some overlapping code? Know any good articles or any source on this, please post.

Comment: You can perfectly have a service in a module even if all the components in that module don't use that service. And creating a module per component seems overkill to me.

Comment: Thanks! :) Was wondering is that the right way :)